# how to pass complex object through data-attribute to modal dialge in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-data-attribute

I was passing a list of Items from Action to view then in view I am displying this list in HTML, if user click on any item in the list then I want to show all the data of that particular item in modal.
I try I lot to pass complete object to modal but all is vain , but if i just pass one property of that particular item

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 portfolio-item" style="background-color:white;padding-bottom:5px;margin-left:2px;margin-right:2px;margin-bottom:2px">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="badge badge-primary">@item.ItemCode</legend>
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail_image_custome" src="~/product_images/2012-Winter-Sweater-for-Men-for-better-outlook.jpg" alt="img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">@item.description</h4>
                            <p class="card-text"><b>@item.CompanyNo (Company no) </b> ipsum dolor sit amet, repellat sequi itaque deserunt!</p>
                            <p class="badge badge-success">@item.Discount% Discount</p>
                            <h5 class="badge">Rs @item.SalePrice</h5>

                            <div style="text-align:center">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view_product openViewProductModal" name="viewProduct" value="View Item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productViewModal" data-viewitem="@item" onclick="show($(this))">
                                    @*<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view_product" id="viewProduct" name="viewProduct" value="View Product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productViewModal" data-id=></button>*@
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
                                    </span> View
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" name="addProductToCart">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> AddToCart
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        }
```

and my JavaScript code is

```
function show(x) {
    console.log(x)
    $("#product_name").text(x.context.dataset.viewitem.description);
}
```

`data-viewitem` data attribute in `<button>` tag carry the item which is clicked.

```
viewitem.description is displaying the description property on item in modal
```

Comment: You can pass the unique Id to the js function which fires the modal dialog and then get the details needed by making an ajax call to server. Once you get the data from server, use that for modal dialog. Another option is to store your entire page view model data to  a local js array and read from that (instead of the ajax call)

Comment: can you please specify the method of storing entire page view model data to a local array.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same passing `item.id` then in the modal again fetching data through ajax.